# flask.cli.NoAppException: The file/path provided (politics) does not appear to exist

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I've been playing around with this for a couple of evenings now, and haven't been able to figure it out, so I'm turning to you.

I've exported my API key and FLASK_APP environment variables, I've ensured all requirements have been installed via pip, yet when I flask run I receive the following warning:

```
Error: The file/path provided (politics) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
```

Here is my code (it is very basic at this point, but it should work)

```
import os
import re
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request, url_for, g
from flask_jsglue import JSGlue

app = Flask(__name__)
JSGlue(app)

# ensure responses aren't cached
if app.config["DEBUG"]:
    @app.after_request
    def after_request(response):
        response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        response.headers["Expires"] = 0
        response.headers["Pragma"] = "n4o-cache"
        return response

# configure get_db = sqlite3
DATABASE = 'propub.db'


def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    return db


@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()


@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/map', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def map():
    if not os.environ.get("API_KEY"):
        raise RuntimeError("API_KEY not set")
    return render_template("map.html", key=os.environ.get("API_KEY"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I have also ran flask in debug mode, and include a screen shot of the debugger output in the hopes that may also help:

[image: screen shot]

I know I currently have unused modules, but it is my understanding that should not matter at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem while working on the Flask ['flaskr'](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/introduction/) tutorial. I had to find and kill the flask process and restart it by ru-running the flask commands:

`$flask initdb` # specific to the tutorial

`$flask run`